# Javascript: parse date to certain string

Tags: javascript, date

I hope you can help me with some JavaScript because I'm a bit lost..

I'm trying to achieve in the easiest way the next format of string for Date object.

```
var now = new Date();
//how to convert to a pattern like this example: "30/1/2012 20:00:00"  ?
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the `format` function in the below link, you can do something like:

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

[JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tftd/UtVnU/

```
var date = new Date();
//how to convert to a pattern like this example: "30/1/2012 20:00:00"  ?
var time = date.getDay()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getYear()+" "+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds();

alert(time) /* Outputs 6/2/112 22:16:15 */
```

You can get everything from the variable `date`.

Comment: Please post your code *here*, because JS Fiddle (semi-frequently) falls over.